# Django Try, except and ObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: django

I am trying to achieve one of the three print messages in order to proceed with my code. Now I am always receiving

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist User has no ambassador_profile.

What I actually expect is print("No amb profile"). Anyone understands what I am doing wrong here?

views.py

```
   user = request.user

        try:
            ambassador = user.ambassador_profile
            selected_event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event, organizer__slug=organizer)
            connected_events = ambassador.events.all()
            if selected_event in connected_events:
                print("You have an ambassador profile and you are connected.")
            else:
                print("You are not connected.")
        except user.ambassador_profile.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print("No amb profile")
```

models.py

```
class AmbassadorProfile(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ambassador_profile',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user does not exists. 
Try this:

```
        try:
            ambassador = user.ambassador_profile
            selected_event = get_object_or_404(Event, slug=event, organizer__slug=organizer)
            connected_events = ambassador.events.all()
            if selected_event in connected_events:
                print("You have an ambassador profile and you are connected.")
            else:
                print("You are not connected.")
        except user.DoesNotExist, user.ambassador_profile.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print("No amb profile")
```

Comment: Unfortunately only gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`back.

Answer (score 0):

What actually solved it was changing `except user.ambassador_profile.ObjectDoesNotExist:` to `except AmbassadorProfile.DoesNotExist:`